# Nested SELECT query in Pyspark DataFrames

Tags: python, sql, select, apache-spark, pyspark

Suppose I have two DataFrames in Pyspark and I'd want to run a nested SQL-like SELECT query, on the lines of

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE b IN
    (SELECT b FROM table2
     WHERE c='1')
```

Now, I can achieve a select query by using `where`, as in

```
df.where(df.a.isin(my_list))
```

given I have selected the *my_list* tuple of values beforehand. How would I perform a nested query in one go instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for know Spark doesn't support subqueries in `WHERE` clause ([SPARK-4226](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-4226)). The closest thing you can get without collecting is `join` and `distinct` roughly equivalent to this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT table1.* 
FROM table1 JOIN table2
WHERE table1.b = table2.b AND table2.c = '1'
```